# Configure message for new user in slack group

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-dialog

I have a slack group and I want to show some welcome message and rules and regulations to follow to new members. Is there a way to do it?

Sorry if I have asked it on wrong platform, in this case where can I ask such question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can introduce a workflow to get this done.
Here is required resources:

https://slack.com/intl/en-in/slack-tips/automatically-onboard-new-channel-members